# What address can i pass as a parameter to kernel module?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

I'm doing kind of test, and I already have spent two weeks researching that topic + yocto.
 
**What I'm trying to do**:

> I'm writing loadable kernel module which "watches" if address (for example, 0x12345, which i have to pass as a parameter or through sysfs) was **read or written** and prints kind of backtrace if it did (i don't know if dump_stack() will bear with it, because, i'm very new to kernel, still have to figure it out, depends on your anwers).

I researched some information about how lkm are written, but i have no idea **where can i use and when** have i pass address to lkm to watch it, all i do for now is writing hello modules and creating chrdev file in dev/ with passed parameters. In short, I have to figure out **what kind of work can i do with such module** (the one i have to write, not hello-modules).

Yes, I asked about it, but the answer was that i have to figure it out by myself, so i asked your help.

Comment: Are you asking how to use sysfs to read an address from the user or how to use hardware watchpoints to catch accesses to that address?

Comment: The question is what can i debug with such module? @MarkPlotnick

Comment: @MarkPlotnick In fact, i care about both, but i can't understand for now where can this module be useful

Comment: [This](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/samples/hw_breakpoint) link has already something i need, so the question is, can i set an address instead of ksymbol? I think that one will surely help me go further. @MarkPlotnick

Comment: If your question is "why do people use watchpoints?", see this paper: https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2009/ols2009-pages-149-158.pdf